# Getting error while running stored procedure with Dyanamic Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I am calling Below Stored procedure in which table name is generating according to current date:

```
    DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_pickalertstatus`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_pickalertstatus`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE msgID  BIGINT (10);
    DECLARE tbl VARCHAR(100);
    SET msgID=(SELECT alertID FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE 
    deliverystatus LIKE '22%' LIMIT 1); 
    IF(msgID IS NOT NULL)THEN
        SET tbl=(SELECT CONCAT('history.tbl_',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%y%m%d")));
        INSERT INTO tbl (MEMBERID,SOURCE,MOBILE,SMPPID,PRIORITY,SMSID
        ,SMSCONTENTTYPE,MESSAGE,REQUESTDATETIME,DR_GROUPID,dr_service_type,
        dr_celleb_msg_id,dr_submit_date,dr_done_date,dr_stat,dr_err,dr_smppid)
        SELECT memberid,SenderID,MSISDN,SMPPID,'1',alertID,'TXT',Message,
        updatetime,'0','PIN','0',DATE_FORMAT(InTime,'ymdHis'),
        DATE_FORMAT(updatetime,'ymdHis'),'DELIVRD',
        '000','03' FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE alertID=msgID;         
    END IF; 
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

i am getting error **"Error Code : 1146 Table 'test.tbl' doesn't exist"**. What i am doing wrong here?

**After suggestion to do this using Prepared statement i have changed above code:**

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_pickalertstatus22`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_pickalertstatus22`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE msgID  BIGINT (10);
    DECLARE tbl VARCHAR(100);
    SET msgID=(SELECT alertID FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE deliverystatus LIKE '22%' LIMIT 1); 
    IF(msgID IS NOT NULL)THEN
        SET tbl=(SELECT CONCAT('history.tbl_',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%y%m%d")));
        SET @sl=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ?',' (MEMBERID,SOURCE,MOBILE,SMPPID,PRIORITY,SMSID,SMSCONTENTTYPE,MESSAGE,REQUESTDATETIME,
        DR_GROUPID,dr_service_type,dr_celleb_msg_id,dr_submit_date,dr_done_date,dr_stat,dr_err,dr_smppid)
            SELECT memberid,SenderID,MSISDN,SMPPID,?,alertID,?,Message,updatetime,?,?,?,DATE_FORMAT(InTime,?),
            DATE_FORMAT(updatetime,?),?,?,? FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE alertID=?');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sl;
        SET @tbl=tbl;
        SET @pr='06';
        SET @txt='TXT';
        SET @grp='0';
        SET @srtyp='PIN';
        SET @clmsg='0';
        SET @intm='%y%m%d%H%i%s';
        SET @outm='%y%m%d%H%i%s';
        SET @drst='DELIVRD';
        SET @drerr='000';
        SET @drsmp='03';
        SET @msg=msgID;

        EXECUTE stmt USING @tbl,@pr,@txt,@grp,@srtyp,@clmsg,@intm,@outm,@drst,@drerr,@drsmp,@msg;       
    END IF; 
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**But still its not working? and getting an error**

```
  Error Code : 1064
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '? MEMBERID,SOURCE,MOBILE,SMPPID,PRIORITY,SMSID,
SMSCONTENTTYPE,MESSAGE,REQUESTDA' at line 1
```

**While executing prepare statement with query string:**

```
    EXECUTE stmt USING '06','TXT','0','PIN','0','%y%m%d%H%i%s'
,'%y%m%d%H%i%s','DELIVRD','000','03';
```

**Getting error :**

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near ''06','TXT','0','PIN','0','%y%m%d%H%i%s','%y%m%d%H%i%s','DELIVRD',
'000','03';' at line 25
```

Comment: try using a prepared statement, CONCAT the `tbl` value in the string from which to prepare

Comment: If you don't use `PREPARE` with a string, it's not a dynamic query.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Would you please tell me syntax for that

Comment: I've updated my answer. The problem IMO is your trying to use a placeholder (`?`) for the table name. I don't think that's possible

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ok , but now i am trying to do same without '?' for table name 'tbl' but getting error in execute statement command ..see latest edit..

Answer (score 0):

In view of your update: don't use a placeholder for the tbl name, CONCAT it in the query string, like I did, to avoid the syntax error near `? (`. Note the `?` before the field names? it's not being replaced by `@tbl`.
Also loose the `@` signs. You're creating session variables (stay in memory during the entire session), which is only useful when needed. Inside a stored procedure, they're irrelevant. After the procedure returns, the variables it uses can, and should be GC'ed.

Use a prepared statement:

```
SET tbl=(SELECT CONCAT('history.tbl_',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%y%m%d"))); -- set tbl as you normally would
PREPARE stmt FROM
CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', tbl, -- tbl is concatenated here
       ' (MEMBERID,SOURCE,MOBILE,SMPPID,PRIORITY,SMSID
        ,SMSCONTENTTYPE,MESSAGE,REQUESTDATETIME,DR_GROUPID,dr_service_type,
        dr_celleb_msg_id,dr_submit_date,dr_done_date,dr_stat,dr_err,dr_smppid)
        SELECT memberid,SenderID,MSISDN,SMPPID,?,alertID,?,Message,
        updatetime,?,?,?,DATE_FORMAT(InTime,?),
        DATE_FORMAT(updatetime,?),?,
        ?,?
        FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE alertID=msgID;');

EXECUTE stmt USING '1', 'TXT', '0', 'PIN', '0', 'ymdHis', 'ymdHis', 'DELIVRD','000', '03';
```

Something like that should do the trick, [More info here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Another way to go about this, still using prepared statements, could be dropping the placeholders:

```
CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', tbl,
       ' (MEMBERID,SOURCE,MOBILE,SMPPID,PRIORITY,SMSID
           ,SMSCONTENTTYPE,MESSAGE,REQUESTDATETIME,DR_GROUPID,dr_service_type,
          dr_celleb_msg_id,dr_submit_date,dr_done_date,dr_stat,dr_err,dr_smppid)
          SELECT memberid,SenderID,MSISDN,SMPPID,\'1\',alertID,\'TXT\',Message,
          updatetime,\'0\',\'PIN\',\'0\',DATE_FORMAT(InTime,\'ymdHis\'),
         DATE_FORMAT(updatetime,\'ymdHis\'),\'DELIVRD\',
        \'000\',\'03\' FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE alertID=msgID');
```

Just escape the quotes, or delimit the concatenation strings using double quotes. 
Not sure about the `DATE_FORMAT` formats, though... shouldn't it be `'%Y%d%m'`?

Comment: How can i will provide value for "tbl"?

Comment: @Ekansh: I've added _your_ code, how you set the tbl variable, and added comment showing where you're inserting the tbl value into the query

Comment: @Ekansh: I did, perhaps do use variables (only without the `@` preceding the names), or just concatenate them into the query as is. A prepared statement needn't contain placeholders, it's just a way to build queries dynamically